# Imagen Cambia de nombre en servidor - PHP

Tags: php, sql

**Actualizado:** Alguien que me pueda ayudar con este código amigos, tengo que guardar una imagen en servidor y base de datos. El problema es que guarda la imagen en el servidor, pero la consulta de insert que tengo enseguida no se ejecuta.

```
//*--------------------------------Se guarda la imagen----------------------------*
$file = $_FILES["file"];
$nombre = getUniqueName()."";
$tipo = $file["type"];
$ruta_provisional = $file["tmp_name"];
$size = $file["size"];
$carpeta = "upload/";

switch ($tipo) {
    case 'image/jpg':
        $tipo = JPG;
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $tipo = JPEG;
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        $tipo = PNG;
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $tipo = GIF;
        break;
    default:
        die("Error, el archivo no es una imagen"); 
}  


$src = $carpeta.$nombre;
move_uploaded_file($ruta_provisional, $src);
changeSize($src, 500, $tipo);
echo "<img src='$src'>";

  //Aqui necesito ingresar $src a la bd, pero no se ejecuta(La sentencia esta probada y funciona correctamente)

 $con = Conectar();
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO bolsa (id, tipo_bolsa, titulo, imagen, descripcion, categoria, fecha, sueldo) VALUES (:id, :tipo_bolsa, :titulo, :imagen, :descripcion, :categoria, :fecha, :sueldo)';
    $q = $con->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':tipo_bolsa'=>$tipo_bolsa, ':titulo'=>$titulo, ':imagen'=>$src, ':descripcion'=>$descripcion, ':categoria'=>$categoria, ':fecha'=>$fecha, ':sueldo'=>$sueldo));
```

Comment: de donde obtienes los valores para hacer el insert? $q->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':tipo_bolsa'=>$tipo_bolsa, ':titulo'=>$titulo, ':imagen'=>$src, ':descripcion'=>$descripcion, ':categoria'=>$categoria, ':fecha'=>$fecha, ':sueldo'=>$sueldo));

Comment: Los obtengo todos de un formulario, solo que aqui no estoy incluyendo ese codigo, es un simple:
$tipo_bolsa = $_Post['tipo_bolsa'];
Pero como decia, si quito el codigo que me sube la imagen, el insert funciona bien, el problema es al combinarlos, nada despues de el codigo que sube mi imagen se ejecuta, que es donde tengo mi sentencia sql

Comment: Logs de apache de cunado se ejecuta el php?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que cuando se sube el fichero, PHP renombra el archivo para almacenarlo al directorio temporal, cuando lo mueves, le debes asignar el nombre definitivo.

Answer (score 2):

Algo no queda claro. Dices: "**El problema es que si las guarda pero con diferente nombre... tengo una funcion la cual le da un nombre único**" y luego respondes esto "**Pues lo que realmente busco es darle un nobre unico, para que cuando pudieran subir dos imagenes iguales estas no se sobrescriban**" a @rodrigomx.

Tu lógica esta bien. Se debe llamar la función **getUniqueName()**, guardar el nombre en una variable y usarla como parámetro en el insert y al guardar la imagen en el servidor. Se deben asignar nombres/id's únicos al momento de guardar imágenes en tu servidor para que estas no se sobrescriban.

Si el problema es otro creo que deberías explicarte mejor.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la publicacion amigo,  necesito guardar la imagen en el servidor y el nombre en la base de datos, mi logia es que se suba la imagen al servidor, y una ves ahi me guarde el nombre en la db, el problema es que la consulta de insert no se ejecuta, como se ve en mi codigo...

Comment: ¿Marca algún error?

Andaba viendo un ejemplo.

En tu código, al último, el nombre de las variables no debe ir sin los **dos puntos ":"** ¿? 

Es decir:
**$q->execute(array('id'=>$id, 'tipo_bolsa'=>$tipo_bolsa...**

Comment: En mi servidor hay un archivo qu recibe los errores y no marca nada, el insert estoy seguro que esta bien, por que si quito el codigo de file, me lo hace normalmente, poniendole un valor x en imagen. El problema estar al agragar el codigo que ingresa la imagen al servidor, despues de ese codigo no se ejecuta ya nada, no puedo ponerlo antes ya que necesito hacer el insert una vez se halla guardado la img

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu código funciona bien como es debido. La razón por la cual la guarda con nombre diferente es para que si suben una imagen con el mismo nombre, estas dos imágenes no se sobreescriban.

Lo que puedes hacer es cambiar la siguiente linea:

```
$nombre = getUniqueName();
```

De una manera similar a:

```
$file = $_FILES["file"];
$nombre = basename($file["name"]);
```

De modo que usará el nombre del archivo que subiste.

Tienes que notar que tu código no está validando que en verdad hayan subido o enviado una imagen, así que agrega las validaciones o tendrás errores.

Comment: Pues lo que realmente busco es darle un nobre unico, para que cuando pudieran subir dos imagenes iguals estas no se sobrescriban, por eso el uso de la funcion, y si..realmente no estoy validando nada, esto de archivos adjuntos me esta dando problema la verdad nunca lo habia implementado y no se por donde moverme

Comment: entonces no entiendo por que no querias que te generara otro nombre, sobre tu problema de validaciones lo que tienes que hacer primero antes de hacer el Insert a la base de datos es verificar con un if si enverdad estas entrando a la seccion por medio de un POST, enseguida tienes que validar que exista un archivo en el POST que enviaste, esto lo puedes revisar por la red los metodos, y enseguida ya que estas seguro que se guardo correctamente es hacer el Inserte con la informacion.